# Minimum number of links needed to connect every vertex of a $4$-dimensional hypercube

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recursive-algorithms, discrete-optimization, pattern-recognition

Let $G_2^4 :=\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} \times \{0,1\}$ be a set of $2^4$ points in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Which is the minimum number of straight lines connected at their endpoints (i.e., the shortest polygonal chain) needed to join all the vertices of $G_2^4$ ?

Now, let us call this optimum value $h(2,k)$, where $k$ is the number of dimensions we are taking into account. 
We know that $h(2,2)=3$ and $h(2,3)=6$ (e.g., $(1,0,0)$-$(0,0,0)$-$(2,2,2)$-$(\frac{1}{2},-1,\frac{1}{2})$-$(-\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2})$-$(1,1,0)$-$(1,1,0)$ is a valid solution - for details see [GENERAL UNCROSSING COVERING PATHS INSIDE THE AXIS-ALIGNED BOUNDING BOX](https://ejournal2.undip.ac.id/index.php/jfma/article/download/12053/6717)) so that $h(2,4) \leq 2 \cdot h(2,3) + 1 = 13$.

Is this value optimal? Could we answer the same question for any $k > 3$? 
I am persuaded that $h(2,4) \leq 12$, but the problem is completely open.

Answer (score 2):

Happy to announce that we have fully solved the general case of the above, formally and constructively proving the existence of optimal covering cycles, for any given choice of $k \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$ for the set $G_2^k :=\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} \times \cdots \times \{0,1\}$, with exactly $3 \cdot 2^{k-2}$ links.
Since no covering trail for the same set of nodes (i.e., the $2^k$ vertices of a $k$-cube, for any $k \geq 2$) can have less than $3 \cdot 2^{k-2}$ links, those cycles are also minimum-link covering trails.
Moreover, it is possible to touch once (and only once) all the Steiner points of any of the minimum-link covering cycles mentioned above, with the only exception of the first/last one (this is mandatory in order to close the covering path and get a cycle).

Here is the link of our preprint that has just been announced on the arXiv, any comments are welcome: https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.11216